# Class of aov object and error term an issue for post hoc testing in R

Tags: r

I am running the following code in R as part of a repeated measures anova analysis:

```
model1 = aov(GazeCueTarget.RT ~ ProbeState * RecallType * CueType 
             + Error(Subject/(ProbeState * RecallType * CueType)), edata.cue.only)
```

This three factor anova has three levels for ProbeState, two for RecallType and two for CueType. The issue I have is that I was told by my academic supervisor to include an error term (see above) to account for any within subject error present. Yet when I do so I run into problems for further testing. I can produce a summary of my results but am unable to run either `leveneTest(model1)` or

```
posthoc = TukeyHSD(x=model1, 'ProbeState', conf.level=0.95)
```

This is an issue because I found a main effect of ProbeState but am unable differentiate where the significant difference lies. I believe the issue stems from the fact that the inclusion of the error term in my model changes the class of the R anova object. If I run `class(model1)` I can see that the output is shown as "aovlist" and "listof". Whereas if I run `class(model1)` where model 1 does not include the error term then I get "aov" and "lm". Within the help section of `TukeyHSD()`it says that the function is to be used on x which is usually a model object with an aov fit.

My question is regarding if I have written my error term within the anova incorrectly? Is there another post hoc test I should be using? I want to go ahead with the anova. I don't want to be changing the analysis to a regression/linear mixed model.

Any clear help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should say the error I get upon running TukeyHSD is as follows: Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") : no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "c('aovlist', 'listof')"